# Parsing XML with PHP, print array of tag values based on specific attribute value

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have an XML file that looks something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root fileType="hierarchy" schema_version="1.1.1">
    <group id="978407" subtype="Web Section">
        <attribute definition_id="1294" is_name="true" type="text">
            <data language="English" label="Web Section">3.6V Drill Drivers</data>
        </attribute>
        <group id="884622" subtype="Product">
            <attribute definition_id="11" is_name="true" is_identifier="true" type="text">
                <data language="English" label="Product Name">Bosch IXO IV Cordless Screwdriver 3.6V (1.5Ah)</data>
            </attribute>
            <attribute definition_id="15" type="text">
                <data language="English" label="Brand">Bosch</data>
            </attribute>
            <attribute definition_id="18" type="text">
                <data language="English" label="Model">IXO IV</data>
            </attribute>
```

I'm wanting to parse it and extract such things as the value of "Model" (for the sake of clarity the value would be 'IXO IV' or the value of the 'id' attribute (978407 or 884622).

I want this done using a foreach loop and the values added to a csv.

so far my PHP looks like this

```
<?php

// xml source
$filexml='3-6v-drill-drivers.xml';

if (file_exists($filexml))
{
    // headers variable
    $headers = array("sku", "attribute_set_code", "categories","name", "description","short_description","weight","speed","model","url_key","image","additional_images","accessories","alternatives");

    //xml object var
    $drillData = simplexml_load_file($filexml) or die("Me no understand");

   

$products = $drillData->xpath('/Root/group/group[@subtype="Product"]/attribute[@*]');

    //create the file
    $fh = fopen("testtttt.csv", "w");

    //create headers
    fputcsv($fh, $headers);

    //iterate over object
    foreach ($products as $product)
    {

        $put_arr = array($product->data['label="Model"'],$product->data['label="Brand"']);

        fputcsv($fh, $put_arr);

    }
    fclose($fh);  
}

?>
```

It's not working... I've also tried defining it using xpath within the loop ($put_arr = array($product->xpath('/data/[@label="Brand"]'), also to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This xpath would get the requested values in a single query

```
//group/@id | //group[@subtype="Product"]/attribute/data[@label="Model"]/text()'
```

> id="978407"
> id="884622"
> IXO IV